# Problems with arrays in an image slider

Tags: arrays, swift, image

I implemented this image slider to my App: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9NhtI2XlGM
Now I want to add functionality to that image slider. I have two arrays:

"imgArr" which stores my pictures as in the original code. The second array is called "welcheNote" and it stores a letter like "E" or "F". Now I want 
to display the `welcheNote[1]` when the first image is displayed. Then `welcheNote[2]` when the second image is displayed.

I tried `note.text = welcheNote[indexPath.row]` inside

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        print(indexPath.row)
        note.text = welcheNote[indexPath.row]

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? DataCollectionViewCell
        cell?.img.image = imgArr[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
```

but this has an unexpected behavior. indexPath.row first shows number of 0 but if I swipe to get the new picture it immediately shows number 2 ...

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class Altissimo: UIViewController {

    var imgArr = [UIImage(named: "altissimoE"),
                  UIImage(named: "altissimoF"),
                  UIImage(named: "altissimoFis"),
                  UIImage(named: "altissimoFis2"),
                  UIImage(named: "altissimoG"),
                  UIImage(named: "altissimoGis"),
                  UIImage(named: "altissimoA"),
                  UIImage(named: "altissimoBb"),
                  UIImage(named: "altissimoB"),
                  UIImage(named: "altissimoC"),
                  UIImage(named: "altissimoCis"),
                  UIImage(named: "altissimoD"),
                  UIImage(named: "altissimoEb"),
                  UIImage(named: "altissimoEhigh"),
                  UIImage(named: "altissimoFhigh")
                  ]

    var welcheNote = ["E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "Bb", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "Eb", "E", "F"]

    let avPlayer = AVPlayer()
    var pathToDrone: String = "A440HzOrgel"

    @IBOutlet weak var colltionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var note: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playButtonFingerings: UIButton!

    @IBAction func playButtonActionFingerings(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if playButtonFingerings.currentBackgroundImage == UIImage(named: "play") {
            playButtonFingerings.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "pause"), for: .normal)
            let path = Bundle.main.path( 
                forResource: pathToDrone, ofType: "mp3")!
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            let ava = AVAsset(url: url)
            let avItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: ava)
            avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: avItem)
            avPlayer.play()
        } else {
            playButtonFingerings.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "play"), for: .normal)
            avPlayer.pause()
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

extension Altissimo: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imgArr.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        note.text = welcheNote[indexPath.row]

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? DataCollectionViewCell
        cell?.img.image = imgArr[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
}

extension Altissimo: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = UIScreen.main.bounds
        return CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see the scroll view delegate methods anywhere? How do you scroll it?

Comment: I did that, like in the video, with the storyboard. Drag and drop. Yet I don't fully understand why it works. But it does. There is another file called "DataCollectionViewCell.swift" which a little bit of code: import UIKit
class DataCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
}. The images are shown in a CollectionView cell. Hope that's answers you comment.

Comment: No, sorry, i avoid using storyboards. But maybe it has something with your deque of cells to do, try setting `uiimageview.image = nil` in a `prepareForReuse` in cell.

Comment: Image pretty new to Swift and I'm afraid not to understand...I thought the problem ist just in the class Altissimo